# Ubuntu alternate install CD kernel modules

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

I'm using Ubuntu alternate install CD to customize the installation process. I have a hardware that uses Realtak 8188CE chipset for wireless network. If I boot into a LiveCD environment I can connect to network with no problems. The problem that I hace is that alternate CD does not contain kernel modules for that chipset.

How can I add additional modules to the kernel that is used by alternate installation CD?